# Fast Hashtable in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashtable, chess

I'm creating a chess program that utilizes a hash table of previously evaluated positions to (hopefully) reduce search time. Only problem is I'm using an ArrayList to store the hash values and the lookup time increases based on how many positions i've stored. How can I get a hash table which has a lookup time independent of it's current size? (Forgive me, I'm kinda a noob at java, objective c is really my thing)

Edit: If it matters, I'm using the Zobrist fast hashing technique. Based on some trials, I've determined that it is NOT the generation of the hash keys that takes up the large amount of time. The hashing methods is very fast and its effect on the speed is almost unnoticeable.

Comment: Use a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (or a `HashSet`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.HashMap` is your best bet. Key lookups are `O(1)` (amortised) and it's a very good general purpose HashMap.

That's not to say that it is optimal: you could certainly design a custom hashmap implementation to be better for your special case if you know how and have a lot of time/determination. But a regular HashMap is definitely the place to start - you can always optimise later.

Answer (score 5):

The standard Java HashMap is pretty good and already available to you, but if you want the screamingly fastest map in Java use Trove ( http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/html/overview.html ) which is filled with data structures that are optimized for performance.

Comment: Thanks guys, I used the HashMap, it's working well! Even though it does make my evaluation a little slower, the time made up by the cached positions more than makes up for it!

Answer (score 5):

First a preliminary note: In chess jargon, the term [transposition table](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Transposition+Table) is more common than "hash table" and will give you better search results on Google.

With this in mind, there is an important difference between a transposition table and a general purpose hash tables (e.g, a Java `Map`):

A map is an associative array which guarantees that no existing entry is deleted when a new value is inserted. Normally, this is what you want, but when you write a chess engine, you will soon run out of memory if you don't delete or overwrite old entries.

In contrast, a transposition table is more a cache, which contains only the most recent entries. It can be implementead as a simple fixed-size array, which is addressed by a hash value of the current position. A well-known and very efficient way to compute the key is [Zobrist hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing) (you already mentioned it in your question). This key is used to index the array. When new entries are added, they will simply overwrite the existing entries.

Here is some pseudo-code to illustrate the idea:

```
// the transposition table entry
class TTEntry {
  long hashKey; // should be at least 64-bit to be safe

  // other information, e.g.:
  Move move;
  int distance;
  // ...
}

TTEntry[] ttable = ... // the more memory, the better

Entry getTTEntry(Board board) {
  long hashKey = board.getHashKey();
  int index = hashKey % ttable.length;
  return ttable[index];
}

void store(Board board) {
  Entry entry = getTTEntry(board);
  entry.hashKey = board.getHashKey();
  entry.move = ...;
  entry.distance = ...;
}

void probe(Board board) {
  Entry entry = getTTEntry(board);
  if (entry.hashKey == hashKey) {
    // entry found
    // ... do something with entry.move and entry.distance
  }
}
```

You said you used an `ArrayList` but your lookup time increased with the number of stored positions. If you use the technique in the example above, that can never happen. Not only is it independent of the number of searched positions, but it will also be faster than a `HashMap`, which is a lot more complicated inside.